# how to write splunk query to create a table view

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I have log in Splunk which contains a message in a sequence order

`"message":" ---Abroad country is good COUNTRYID - GERMAN9876-er4-22"`

`"message":" ---Abroad country is good COUNTRYID - GERMAN9876-er4-23"`

`"message":" ---Abroad country is good COUNTRYID - GERMAN9876-er4-24"`

I want to create a table in Splunk dashboard to view using Splunk query with these columns list all the case numbers with the details

```
COUNTRYID
GERMAN9876-er4-22
GERMAN9876-er4-23
GERMAN9876-er4-24
```

I am very new in splunk can someone guide how to start to build where to look for the thing. Any hint or demo will work. Thank you

Comment: Is `COUNTRYID` already defined as a field? If so, it's just `table COUNTRYID`.

Comment: @PM77-1 there multiple places where ```COUNTRYID``` is mentioned but i am looking for this string only

Comment: Your result has 2 rows.  Does it mean that there was one more event? If so, please post sample source data and the desired result,

Comment: Yes there are multiple event more than 100+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use [`rex`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/8.2.4/SearchReference/Rex) to isolate the desired field:

```
index=<your search>
| rex "\"message\":\" ---Abroad country is good COUNTRYID - (?<CountryID>[\w-]+)\""
| table CountryID
```

The above is untested.

Comment: To avoid the need for extra escape characters, the `rex` command can be shortened.  `| rex "COUNTRYID - (?<CountryID>[\w-])"`

Comment: @RichG - In response to my comment OP stated that "*there multiple places where `COUNTRYID` is mentioned but i am looking for this string only*", so I decided to use the full string.

Comment: Good point.  In that case, the embedded quotes need triple-backslashes.

Comment: @RichG - I never had to it before.

Comment: This is something Splunk regex users have complained about for some time, but I just ran a test and, sure enough, a single backslash works.  I wonder when that changed.  I did discover the `rex` command needs a '+' after the ']', however.

Comment: @RichG:  Yes, absolutely.  Fixed.

Comment: @PM77-1 can you have a look once https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71054620/splunk-query-to-create-a-table-view

Comment: @RichG can you have a look once https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71054620/splunk-query-to-create-a-table-view