# Splunk query to create a table view?

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

This event is printed eveytime `UserPin AreaCode AreaNum Sector Short Sem` are unique for each userid and come only inside `User Login successfully` message with timestamp

```
"message":" *** User Login successfully credentials userid 2NANO-323254-7654-4  UserPin - 287654 AreaCode - 98765 AreaNum - 98765 Sector - 87612345 Short Sem - ZEB"
```

Below these two event are only printed when certain conditions are meet. I am very new in Splunk like a naive, how can we write a Splunk query such that take out the userid with UserPin AreaCode AreaNum Sector Short Sem which have the below printed event then only create a table with userid. If below two message are not printed with userid from above message then we should not consider the userid

```
"message": "User Failed to login userid - 2NANO-323254-7654-4"
```

```
"message": "User is from stackoverflow group, on XZ ABCE for userid - 2NAN0-323254-7654-4"
```

this is table structure where i want to fill values

```
UserId | UserPin | AreaCode | AreaNum | Sector | Short_Sem
```

I am very new in splunk can someone guide how to start to build where to look for the thing. Any hint or demo will work. Thank you

Example

```
"message":" *** User Login successfully credentials userid 2NANO-323254-7654-4  UserPin - 287654 AreaCode - 98765 AreaNum - 98765 Sector - 87612345 Short Sem - ZEB"
```

```
"message": "User Failed to login userid - 2NANO-323254-7654-4"
```

```
"message": "User is from stackoverflow group, on XZ ABCE for userid - 2NAN0-323254-7654-4"
```

```
"message":" *** User Login successfully credentials userid 2ABDO-54312-7654-4  UserPin - 287654 AreaCode - 98765 AreaNum - 98765 Sector - 87612345 Short Sem - ZEB"
```

```
"message":" *** User Login successfully credentials userid 2COMA-765234-8653-4  UserPin - 287654 AreaCode - 98765 AreaNum - 98765 Sector - 87612345 Short Sem - ZEB"
```

So we consider first only because that userid have has two more event with same userid and associated all the event have timestamp

```
UserId              | UserPin| AreaCode | AreaNum | Sector   | Short_Sem
2NANO-323254-7654-4 | 287654 | 98765    | 98765   | 87612345 | ZEB
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This question is an expansion of your question at [how to write splunk query to create a table view](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70989206/2227420) so the answer is an expansion of that answer.

First, use `rex` to extract the desired fields.  Then the `stats` command will group the results by userid.  Finally, use the `table` command to display the fields.

````
| makeresults 
| eval data="\"message\":\" *** User Login successfully credentials userid 2NANO-323254-7654-4  UserPin - 287654 AreaCode - 98765 AreaNum - 98765 Sector - 87612345 Short Sem - ZEB\"
    \"message\": \"User Failed to login userid - 2NANO-323254-7654-4\"
    \"message\": \"User is from stackoverflow group, on XZ ABCE for userid - 2NAN0-323254-7654-4\"
    \"message\":\" *** User Login successfully credentials userid 2ABDO-54312-7654-4  UserPin - 287654 AreaCode - 98765 AreaNum - 98765 Sector - 87612345 Short Sem - ZEB\"
    \"message\":\" *** User Login successfully credentials userid 2COMA-765234-8653-4  UserPin - 287654 AreaCode - 98765 AreaNum - 98765 Sector - 87612345 Short Sem - ZEB\"" 
| eval data=split(data,"
") 
| mvexpand data 
| eval _raw=data 
```Everything above is for demo purposes only```
```Extract fields```
| rex "message\":\s*\"\s*(?:\*+\s)?(?<msg>.*?)(?:userid|,)"
| rex "userid\s(?:-\s)?(?<userid>\S+)" 
| rex "UserPin - (?<UserPin>\S+) AreaCode - (?<AreaCode>\S+) AreaNum - (?<AreaNum>\S+) Sector - (?<Sector>\S+) Short Sem - (?<Short_Sem>\S+)"
```Clean up the fields```
| eval userid=trim(userid,"\""), Short_Sem=trim(Short_Sem, "\"")
```Group results```
| stats values(*) as * by userid
```Filter events```
| search (msg="*User Failed to login*") OR (msg="*User is from stackoverflow group*")
| rename userid as UserId
| table UserId UserPin AreaCode AreaNum Sector Short_Sem
````

Comment: I tried this query but it return some wired output it returned me 4 rows but i  just want 1 row only ```UserId              | UserPin| AreaCode | AreaNum | Sector   | Short_Sem
           2NANO-323254-7654-4 | 287654 | 98765    | 98765   | 87612345 | ZEB```

Comment: Hi @RichG I added the image of the query in the question

Comment: Four lines are displayed because there are 4 different userid values.  You can show only 1 line, but how will Splunk know which one?

Comment: That is what i asked in question want to build table where userid has these two string also if not then dont consider those cases ```\"message\": \"User Failed to login userid - 2NANO-323254-7654-4\"
    \"message\": \"User is from stackoverflow group, on XZ ABCE for userid - 2NAN0-323254-7654-4\"```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot @RichG its working fine but i still get two rows added the image any idea like why i am get two rows

Comment: The sample data contains two userid values with the desired strings: `2NANO-323254-7654-4` and `2NAN0-323254-7654-4`